# How to connect through Terminal in OSx

Tags: socks, censorship, obfsproxy, openvpn

My ISP blocks OpenVPN but i can connect to Tor using obfsproxy **(I have to add a socks proxy to obfsproxy config otherwise it won't work either)**. I used obfsproxy as a socks proxy (localhost 9150) in my OpenVPN configuration and when I did that OpenVPN connected to it's server but the problem is when OpenVPN connected, Tor went down because OpenVPN uses Tor to see internet when Tor itself try to use OpenVPN to see internet ...

But there is a solution. When i use Terminal to make a ssh tunnel (*that is now blocked by ISP*) and use that tunnel for Openvpn, everything works fine and ssh connection in Terminal won't drop when OpenVPN connects to VPN server. I want to know how I can make an obfsproxy connection using Terminal?